# C++ : CoCreateInstance for CLSID_FeedsScheduler , get STG_E_FILENOTFOUND in windows10

Tags: com

hr is 0x80030002 returned from CoCreateInstance  , which is STG_E_FILENOTFOUND. login as admin MSA account Search on pc, I found the entry in registry: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4D36777-EAED-4cc5-9FE7-827BE5190B20}\InProcServer32\

Comment: Please help: what could possible reason for this error?

Comment: what caused this error?